# printing new lines with printf assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, newline, printf, nasm

Hi I'm trying to write some assembly code that uses printf to print a given string. I am declaring my strings before use in the .data section and a test example looks as follows:

```
extern printf
extern fflush

LINUX        equ     80H      ; interupt number for entering Linux kernel
EXIT         equ     60       ; Linux system call 1 i.e. exit ()

section .data
    outputstringfmt: db "%s", 0
    sentence0: db "Hello\nWorld\n", 0


segment .text
    global  main


main:
    mov r8, sentence0
    push r8
    call print_sentence
    add rsp, 8
    call os_return

print_sentence:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push r12
    mov r12, [rbp + 16]
    push rsi
    push rdi
    push r8
    push r9
    push r10
    mov rsi, r12
    mov rdi, outputstringfmt
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    xor rax, rax
    call fflush
    pop r10
    pop r9
    pop r8
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    pop r12
    pop rbp
    ret

os_return:
    mov  rax, EXIT      ; Linux system call 1 i.e. exit ()
    mov  rdi, 0     ; Error code 0 i.e. no errors
    syscall     ; Interrupt Linux kernel 64-bit
```

I'm then compiling as follows:

```
nasm -f elf64 test.asm; gcc -m64 -o test test.o
```

And finally running:

```
./test
```

My output is as follows:

```
Hello\nWorld\n
```

I really don't want to split sentence0 up into the following:

```
sentence0: db "Hello", 10, 0
sentence1: db "World", 10, 0
```

and then call the print twice. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better way to do what exactly?

Comment: I don't want to have to split the string up into multiple string declarations. I just want to be able to print the newlines as part of the string and only have to declare it in sentence0.

Comment: Are you saying the \n:s are printed verbatim?

Comment: At the moment they are but I do not want them to be. I want them printed as newlines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NASM accepts strings in single quotes (`'...'`) or double quotes (`"..."`), which are equivalent, and do not provide any escapes; or in backquotes (`` `...` ``), which provide support for C-style escapes, which is what you want.

(See [section 3.4.2, "Character Strings", in the documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2).)

To get actual ASCII newlines in your data in memory, rather than literal backslash n:

```
sentence0: db `Hello\nWorld\n`, 0
```

Or do it manually:

```
sentence0: db 'Hello', 10, 'World`, 10, 0
```

YASM (another NASM-syntax assembler) doesn't accept backticks, so the manual option is your only choice there.

And BTW, you can call `puts` instead of `printf` if you don't have any actual formatting in your format string (leave out the trailing newline).

Answer (score 3):

You have the newlines (\n) in the string to be output. They should be in the format string to be treated as newlines. This solves half of your problem:

```
outputstringfmt: db "%s\n%s\n", 0
sentence0: db "Hello", 0
sentence1: db "World", 0
```

And something like this *should* print newlines after each word:

```
outputstringfmt: db "%s", 0
sentence0: db "Hello", 10 , "World", 10 , 0
```

Comment: I do not have control over where the new lines in the string will be this was just a test example. I have tried using printf in C and you do not need to specify the newlines in the format and it still seems to handle them fine. I was wondering why my assembly doesn't handle them either?

Comment: Might be implementation sensitive. I'm not that familiar with how it "should" behave.

Comment: the C compiler translates \n into a single 0xA character.  it is a string parser thing in the compiler, not printf.  Disassemble what nasm is producing and perhaps there is an option for nasm to parse like a C compiler instead of like an assembler.