# printing function (get segmentation fault)

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, x86-64, intel

am trying to print out a function out put W - X) + (Y - Z), i keep 
getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) when ever i compile
and try to run the program

nasm -felf64 asm_program -o asm_program.o

gcc -m64 asm_program.o -o asm_program

./asm_program

i have searched around but i cant fine the solution. I wanted to ask firstly what does this segmentation fault mean and how it relates to my program, secondly where am making a mistake in my code.

relatively new to assembly by the way

**Program starts here**

```
global main

extern printf

segment .data

    w: DQ  1
    x: DQ  3
    y: DQ  5
    z: DQ  2



   segment .text

   main:

    call compute


   compute:

    mov rax, w
    mov rcx, x
    add rax,rcx

    mov rbx, y
    mov rbp, z
    add rbx, rbp

    mul rbx
    call printf
```

Comment: Always end your programs by a `ret` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula (w-x) + (y-z) conflicts with the code in principle which denotes (w+x) * (y+z) so that's why I'm going to give you an example of.

```
mov   rax, w    Move the address of w into RAX which is 0x601038
mov   rax, [w]  Moves the value @ 0x601038 which is 1.
```

The result we're looking for is 28, so this will do the trick.

```
global main

extern printf
    segment .rodata
Fmt     db  13, 10, 9, 'Result is %d', 13, 10, 13, 10, 0

    segment .data
    w: DQ  1
    x: DQ  3
    y: DQ  5
    z: DQ  2

   segment .text
main:

    call compute
    ret        ; added, or computed is executed a second time

compute:
    mov     rax, [w]
    add     rax, [x]
    mov     rcx, rax

    mov     rax, [y]
    add     rax, [z]
    xor     rdx, rdx
    mul     rcx

    mov rdi, Fmt      ; Format string
    mov rsi, rax      ; Value to be displayed
    call printf
    ret               ; added or program continues executing in the bush
```

There are a lot of ways to skin this cat, this is just simply an example that works.

Answer (score 1):

Bigger problem is: you never call `ret`:

```
global main

extern printf

segment .data

    w: DQ  1
    x: DQ  3
    y: DQ  5
    z: DQ  2



   segment .text

   main:

    call compute
    ret        ; added, or computed is executed a second time

   compute:

    mov rax, w
    mov rcx, x
    add rax,rcx

    mov rbx, y
    mov rbp, z
    add rbx, rbp

    mul rbx
    call printf
    ret      ; added or program continues executing in the bush
```

After that, we would need to see the API of `printf` to be sure it's called with the proper parameters (registers or stack properly initialized). If this is the `printf` I know, it is a variable args function which needs a format like `"%d"` then the argument. I did not see any format in your code.

To print a simple integer, I would avoid using `printf` and would output the result character by character after using a custom integer => string code. It would make your code smaller and more independent (assembly is not done to call C functions all the time :)).

Comment: you have to use a debugger to see what's going on. What are the arguments `printf` expects? is that register or stack? remove the call to `printf`` and see if it ceases to crash.

Comment: i removed the call print now it compiles fine but wont print the answer once it is run. Concerning the arguments for printf i think i mistakenly used it when i was writing another program before that need wall calling a c function

Comment: as you see here, calling printf is not obvious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644965/execution-stuck-at-printf-assembly. Needs pushing stuff on the stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533408/printing-new-lines-with-printf-assembly